# Excel Add text to the existing text values of multiple highlightes cells with different text values

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have cells accros multiple columns that I have identified by highlighting them in red. The values are names of employees separated by Alt Enter. I need to Add a new name (The same name) to all those cells containing multiple names either at the beginning, end or anywhere for that matter.

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly? What did you try?

Comment: I tried using find and replace using format to find the highlighted cells and replaced he format of the cells using the General argument changing @ for @"name to be added" the problem with this is that it displays the correct information but the cell values were not changed. So I would need a function/Code to get the value of the cells and add the new piece of information but I really do not knowhow to do that.

Comment: Could you please provide some example data and expected outcome?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add to the contents of cells only if those cells are highlighted? Use a filter, filter by cell color, then write a formula in a helper column (such as `=A1&" New Name"`) and paste that over the source cell

Comment: Could you provide more information about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To add them to the end, use the following:

```
=IF( ISERROR( FIND(CHAR(10), A1:G1) ), A1:G1, A1:G1 & CHAR(10) & "New Name")
```

To add them to the beginning, use this instead:

```
=IF( ISERROR( FIND(CHAR(10), A1:G1) ), A1:G1, "New Name" & CHAR(10) & A1:G1 )
```

Basically, they look (`FIND()`) for the `Alt-Enter` character and have one of two results. If one exists in a cell in the range, the result is the position of it in that cell (first one in the cell anyway) and that result is a nice, natural result. If one does not exist, an error is produced. So if one does not exist the `ISERROR()` gives True and if one does exist, it gives False. The `IF()` takes that and gives the current cell contents if there is no `Alt-Enter` character (so if there is nothing at all, or a single name, or a sentence, whatever might be there), and gives the current cell contents PLUS the new name if there is an `Alt-Enter` character.

However, it cannot do this in the actual cells where you want the results. So you have to place the formulas in a different set of cells and after giving them a new name to add, you Copy those formula cells, then go to the real data range and `Paste|Special|Values` to overwrite the original data with the new version (that includes the new name).

The cells the formulas would be put into are normally called "helper cells" and while easy to do, can be a problem sometimes. You might think to put them on the row underneath or above the current data cells but other stuff is there already. Awkward... And so on. But folks limit themselves thinking that way. No need for that.

Any time you need to do this, just insert a new sheet into the spreadsheet, put the formulas in IT, copy and paste over to the real sheet, then delete the helper sheet. No muss, no fuss.

And if you don't care to write the formula every time you do that, especially if it's a year later before you do it again, you can accomplish it by putting the formula into a `Named Range` (call it something like `AddName` perhaps). Then it's there with no need to remember just how to write it and when you want to do this, just insert the helper sheet and use the formula `=AddName` (so remembering it is easy, or at least it's easy to locate the Named Range to use!) in however many cells you need. No remembering an unfamiliar formula.

You do not have to put the new name in doublequotes as in the above. You could use a cell reference instead and type the new name there. Or if it is already in a cell somewhere, refer to that cell.

You COULD insert the new name in between names, second in all cells, say. But it would be a rather more complicated formula. And doing it as some odd thing like "the fourth name, but if there aren't three at least already, then as the third and if there aren't three already then the second" would be very much more complicated.

Excel does not let you do a `Find and Replace` in which you would show that you want whatever the cell has in it AND the new thing added. So searching for something like `*ALT-Enter*` and replacing it with `*Alt-EnterNew Name` so you get the original contents and the new name won't work. And there isn't really a good string to hunt for anyway since any cell might have any number of names.

Excel WILL search for cell color in `Find` or `FIND and Replace` but since you can't do a replacement that returns what was there to start with plus the new name, that is of limited value... limited to "none" in this case.